# Jquery not getting form data from forms with that same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm not getting form values on submit of two forms with the same class.

When I submit one of the forms,
a) Jquery submit event is called but values are empty 
b) the submit event is skipped and I'm taken right to the php file where I enter the info into a database

My Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('body').on('submit', '.newStaff', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var firstName= this.firstName.value;
     // do other stuff
       //complete AJAX call
   });
});
```

My forms

```
<form class="newStaff" method="post" action="insertStaff.php">
  <input type="text" name="firstName"  />
  // use other inputs.....
  <input type="submit" value="submit"  />
</form>

<form class="newStaff" method="post" action="insertStaff.php">
  <input type="text" name="firstName"  />
  // use other inputs.....
  <input type="submit" value="submit"  />
</form>
```

Am I not binding correctly?  Haven't had issues like this before. I've always been able to get unique input values based on the form that was submitted.

Comment: What do you mean by "on submit of two forms"? Are you expecting both forms to be submitted at the same time? Or the `submit` handler is not being called? Is jQuery code within `$(function(){})`?

Comment: When I submit one of the forms, the values from that form are either 
a) not being sent
b) the submit event is skipped and I'm taken right to the php file where I enter the info into a database

Comment: Is jQuery code within `jQuery(function(){})`?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
});

Comment: Cannot reproduce https://jsfiddle.net/78c4nqbv/

Answer (score 0):

my be you can use function **[eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)** jquery for this

```js
$(function() {
  $('body').on('submit', '.newStaff', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var firstName = $('.newStaff input[name="firstName"]').eq(0).val();
    alert(firstName);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="newStaff" method="post" action="insertStaff.php">
  <input type="text" name="firstName"  value="1 2 3"/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<br/>

<form class="newStaff" method="post" action="insertStaff.php">
  <input type="text" name="firstName" value="a b c"/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```